# 'this' parent selector not working

Tags: jquery, css, parent, children

http://jsfiddle.net/raduv118/

I've got two jQuery functions, respectively either showing or hiding a div, nested inside a div, nested inside a list.

First function applies CSS `display: block`, and the second one applies `display: none`. But the second function is not working.

Check out the fiddle.

1. Click the green li element to load the first function.
2. Click the orange div header to load the second function. (NOT WORKING)

What I wan't to achieve, in plain English, is two functions. First one to open the child, second one to close the parent.

NOTE: NO other selector than parent and child must be used, thereby no specific ID's. The code is meant to be applied onto a whole lot of the same structures.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.listcontainer').click(function () {
        $(this).children().css('display', 'block');
    })
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".popup_header").click(function () {
        $(this).parent('div').css("display", "none");
    })
});
```

Comment: Just a tip: JQuery has a shortcut for `display` changes... use `$('something').show()` and `$('something').hide()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is because the click event bubbles up the DOM, so clicking on the inner div makes it appear, but then the parent click event fires which immediately hides it again. You need to use `stopPropagation()` on the click event of the inner `div`:

```
$(".popup_header").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent('div').css("display", "none");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/raduv118/4/)

Also note that you can put all your code inside a sing DOMReady handler.

Comment: Seconds... and you added a fiddle before I could give you mine! Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/raduv118/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but the first function works perfect, because you are targeting the correct div, in the second stage, you click and you are targeting both divs, so your code is actually hiding it and showing it again. It goes in both functions.

Function 2 triggers hiding and function 1 is triggering to because is a parent and all that is inside $('.listcontainer') is clickable.

## Solution:

Separate the listeners area, or simple remove the listener and add it again.